# incompatible Point Data Format ID

Tags: r, lidr

I’m working on an area covered by two datasets, one from 2010 and the other from 2015. The former was provided as XYZ divided into ground, nonground and vegetation. So I read the files, merged them accordingly, and then converted the final file to a LAS format, creating a brand new `las` object as follows:

```
  las = matrix(c(1695880.667,5094022.807,1732.313,
         1695718.494,5094022.806,1751.88,
         1695520.069,5094022.835,1747.236,
         1695823.296,5094022.837,1742.622,
         1695799.426,5093979.505,1745.042,
         1695785.666,5093958.185,1748.842,
         1695782.845,5093959.275,1749.202,
         1695782.755,5093956.935,1748.812,
         1695781.645,5093959.925,1749.322,
         1695781.565,5093957.575,1748.922,
         1695707.754,5093936.793,1754.181,
         1695707.604,5093932.223,1753.701,
         1695339.365,5093990.103,1800.192,
         1695339.285,5093980.463,1801.392,
         1695292.044,5093961.072,1801.752,
         1695290.794,5093959.412,1802.372,
         1695286.413,5093988.113,1804.821,
         1695286.243,5093983.533,1804.001,
         1695284.753,5093980.903,1803.191,
         1695282.093,5093976.383,1802.451,
         1695282.053,5093974.343,1802.501,
         1695282.033,5093972.353,1802.651,
         1695280.783,5093976.813,1802.741,
         1695279.413,5093970.923,1803.511,
         1695253.913,5093962.762,1810.801),ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) # just a sample
  las = as.data.frame(las)
  colnames(las) = c("X","Y","Z")
  las = LAS(las)
  las = las_rescale(las, xscale = 0.01, yscale = 0.01, zscale = 0.01) # added later to make it work together with data from 2015 
  lidR::projection(las) = 3003L
```

I then created the catalog for the whole area (so including the 2 scans):

```r
ctg = readALSLAScatalog(las.folder, chunk_size = 0, chunk_buffer = 25)
#> Be careful, some tiles seem to overlap each other. lidR may return incorrect outputs with edge artifacts when processing this catalog.
```

Unfortunately, running `grid_canopy` to create the DSM, I got the following error:

```r
r = grid_canopy(ctg, p2r(subcircle = 0.2, na.fill=tin()), res=1)
#> Error: Different files have different Point Data Format ID and are incompatible.
```

I checked with `las_check` a file from each dataset and I found that there were different scale factors, so I added in the abovementioned procedure the `las_rescale` step and checked again:

```r
lascheck(las2010)

Checking the data
- Checking coordinates... ✓
- Checking coordinates type... ✓
- Checking coordinates range... ✓
- Checking coordinates quantization... ✓
- Checking attributes type... ✓
- Checking ReturnNumber validity... ✓
- Checking NumberOfReturns validity... ✓
- Checking ReturnNumber vs. NumberOfReturns... ✓
- Checking RGB validity... ✓
- Checking absence of NAs... ✓
- Checking duplicated points... ✓
- Checking degenerated ground points... ✓
- Checking attribute population...
 'PointSourceID' attribute is not populated
 'ScanDirectionFlag' attribute is not populated
 'EdgeOfFlightline' attribute is not populated
- Checking gpstime incoherances skipped
- Checking flag attributes... ✓
- Checking user data attribute... ✓
Checking the header
- Checking header completeness... ✓
- Checking scale factor validity... ✓
- Checking point data format ID validity... ✓
- Checking extra bytes attributes validity... ✓
- Checking the bounding box validity... ✓
- Checking coordinate reference system... ✓
Checking header vs data adequacy
- Checking attributes vs. point format... ✓
- Checking header bbox vs. actual content... ✓
- Checking header number of points vs. actual content... ✓
- Checking header return number vs. actual content... ✓
Checking coordinate reference system...
- Checking if the CRS was understood by R... ✓
Checking preprocessing already done 
- Checking ground classification... yes
- Checking normalization... no
- Checking negative outliers... ✓
- Checking flightline classification... no
```

```r
lascheck(las2015)
    
Checking the data
- Checking coordinates... ✓
- Checking coordinates type... ✓
- Checking coordinates range... ✓
- Checking coordinates quantization... ✓
- Checking attributes type... ✓
- Checking ReturnNumber validity... ✓
- Checking NumberOfReturns validity... ✓
- Checking ReturnNumber vs. NumberOfReturns... ✓
- Checking RGB validity... ✓
- Checking absence of NAs... ✓
- Checking duplicated points...
⚠ 141 points are duplicated and share XYZ coordinates with other points
- Checking degenerated ground points... ✓
- Checking attribute population... ✓
- Checking gpstime incoherances
✗ 2292 pulses (points with the same gpstime) have points with identical ReturnNumber
- Checking flag attributes... ✓
- Checking user data attribute... ✓
Checking the header
- Checking header completeness... ✓
- Checking scale factor validity... ✓
- Checking point data format ID validity... ✓
- Checking extra bytes attributes validity... ✓
- Checking the bounding box validity... ✓
- Checking coordinate reference system... ✓
Checking header vs data adequacy
- Checking attributes vs. point format... ✓
- Checking header bbox vs. actual content... ✓
- Checking header number of points vs. actual content... ✓
- Checking header return number vs. actual content... ✓
Checking coordinate reference system...
- Checking if the CRS was understood by R... ✓
Checking preprocessing already done 
- Checking ground classification... yes
- Checking normalization... no
- Checking negative outliers... ✓
- Checking flightline classification... yes
```

The headers report that

```r
las2010@header
    File signature:           LASF 
    File source ID:           0 
    Global encoding:
     - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
     - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
     - Well Know Text: CRS is GeoTIFF 
     - Aggregate Model: false 
    Project ID - GUID:        00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
    Version:                  1.2
    System identifier:         
    Generating software:      rlas R package 
    File creation d/y:        38/2022
    header size:              227 
    Offset to point data:     297 
    Num. var. length record:  1 
    Point data format:        0 
    Point data record length: 20 
    Num. of point records:    825250 
    Num. of points by return: 825250 0 0 0 0 
    Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01 
    Offset X Y Z:             1695029 5093022 0 
    min X Y Z:                1695030 5093023 1640.02 
    max X Y Z:                1696030 5094023 1847.25 
    Variable Length Records (VLR):
       Variable Length Record 1 of 1 
           Description: by LAStools of rapidlasso GmbH 
           Tags:
              Key 3072 value 3003 
    Extended Variable Length Records (EVLR):  void
```

```r
las2015@header
    File signature:           LASF 
    File source ID:           0 
    Global encoding:
     - GPS Time Type: GPS Week Time 
     - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
     - Well Know Text: CRS is GeoTIFF 
     - Aggregate Model: false 
    Project ID - GUID:        00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
    Version:                  1.2
    System identifier:         
    Generating software:      rlas R package 
    File creation d/y:        283/2015
    header size:              227 
    Offset to point data:     297 
    Num. var. length record:  1 
    Point data format:        1 
    Point data record length: 28 
    Num. of point records:    4823256 
    Num. of points by return: 1916037 1426474 855730 409244 155215 
    Scale factor X Y Z:       0.01 0.01 0.01 
    Offset X Y Z:             1689576 5075853 0 
    min X Y Z:                1689577 5075853 1107.62 
    max X Y Z:                1690387 5076988 1409.16 
    Variable Length Records (VLR):
       Variable Length Record 1 of 1 
           Description: by LAStools of rapidlasso GmbH 
           Tags:
              Key 3072 value 3003 
    Extended Variable Length Records (EVLR):  void
```

I'm never too sure about the best procedure to apply when creating new `las` objects such as those coming from old text files, but it's the first time that the analyses get blocked by such an issue and I didn't find any guidance on the kind of error I met and the Point Data Format ID, except for the ASPRS document citing: *Point Data Format ID: The point data format ID corresponds to the point data record format type. LAS 1.2 defines types 0, 1, 2 and 3.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In version 3.2.4 (available on [github](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR)) this constraint has been relaxed so you can read two files that are incompatible (see also [#508](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/discussions/508)). Notice that v3.2.4 is unlikely to be released on CRAN because next version will likely be v4.0.0

Be careful however, the fact that the constraint is less strict does not mean the files became magically compatible. If you have PDF 0 (no gpstime, no RGB) with las PDF 3 (gpstime + RGB) they are incompatible because they do not have the same number of attributes and consequently cannot be read as one. In this case the first file has the precedence and gpstime and RGB can be either skipped or zeroed in the second files depending on the format of the first file read.

Also you almost never need to rescale manually. The rescaling will happen on-the-fly when reading two files with different scale factors. Assigning a scale factor from external data as you did with the matrix can be done automatically. Your coordinates have 3 digits of accuracy and this is detected properly by `LASheader`

```r
las = as.data.frame(las)
colnames(las) = c("X","Y","Z")
header = LASheader(las)
las = LAS(las, header)
lidR::projection(las) = 3003L
```

Because your file has only XYZ, `lidR` infered a point data format 0

```r
las
#> class        : LAS (v1.2 format 0)
#> ...
```

But you can assign something else

```r
las@header@PHB[["Point Data Format ID"]] = 2L
```

Comment: great, I'm gonna download it istantly! I added `las_rescale` because in the beginning I thought it could be somehow part of the problem (2010 had 0.001 while 2015 with 0.01), so now I'll remove it. Is there any release plan for `lidR` v4?

Comment: Relatively soon (a matter of weeks). But you can beta test it right know. Checkout the [changelogs](https://github.com/r-lidar/lidR/blob/devel/NEWS.md)